# How to use c++20 concepts to compile-time enforce match of number of args for given type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm using policy-based design, and I have several policies implementation (that use same interface), but one of the policies needs a different number of args for construction.

So i've used in my class variadic template arguments (`typename... InitArgs`)
and I forward them using `std::forward` to contructor of policy type.

example:

```
class Policy1 : public PolicyBase
{
    Policy1(int arg1, std::string arg2);
}

class Policy2 : public PolicyBase
{
    Policy2(int arg1);
}

template<typename T>
concept PolicyConept = std::is_base_of<PolicyBase, T>::value;

template<PolicyConept T = Policy1, typename... InitArgs>
class PolicyManager
{
   public:
   PolicyManager(InitArgs... args) 
   {
       _policyState = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<InitArgs>(args)...);
   }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> _policyState;
}

int main()
{
   auto policy1 = std::make_unique<PolicyManager<Policy1>>(1,"2");
   auto policy2 = std::make_unique<PolicyManager<Policy2>>(1);

}
```

**I'm looking for a way to use concepts (introduced in C++20), that can perform compile-time check, to ensure the number of arguments provide is enough to build from them the given type**.

so would expect the following code to fail at compile time:

```
int main()
    {
       auto policy1 = std::make_unique<PolicyManager<Policy1>>(1); // missing argument
    }
```

I was attempting to use the concept `std::constructible_from` to accomplish that,
but I'm not sure how the syntax would apply for `args...`.

Would appreciate the help

Comment: Neither the `main` nor the constructor can return `void`, this is not valid C++.

Comment: You are right, it was a typo. Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a constraint on the constructor.

```
    template <typename... Args>
    PolicyManager(Args&&... args) requires std::constructible_from<T, Args&&...>
```

Note also that the `Args` template parameter pack should be on the constructor to ensure the arguments are correctly forwarded.